# `describeBy` with 2 grouping variables and mat= TRUE produces error "subscript out of bounds"

Tags: r, psych

getting a `"subscript out of bounds"` error in `describeBy` summary stat. when grouping by two variables and `mat=TRUE` for dataset > 1000 obs. 
It Works ok for large dataset if mat=TRUE is removed and then it is a list output.
 Using psych version 1.8.12.

```
Error in [<-(tmp, var, group + 1, value = dim.names[[group]][[groupi]]) : 
subscript out of bounds error
```

any help is appreciated

"data" has 120951 observations, 6 variables.

```
prod_metrics <- describeBy(list(data$TOTALCHARGES, data$NONCOVEREDCHARGES,
                            data$COVEREDCHARGES, data$HCE_TARGET_AMT),
                     list(data$PARENTCLIENTCODE, data$RECEIVEDDATE), mat = TRUE, digits = 2)
```

Here is the structure of data:

```r
dput(head(data))
structure(list(TOTALCHARGES = c(216, 496.68, 150, 610, 6259.73, 1020.97), PARENTCLIENTCODE = structure(c(468L, 253L, 456L, 456L, 43L, 167L), .Label = c("5STAR-P", "AAE-P", "AALT-P", "ABA-P", 
"ABN-P", "ACN-P","XIND-P","XKAI-P","XOXF-P","XPACI-P","XPIC-P","XRX-P","XSFH-P","XSISTERP"), class = "factor"), RECEIVEDDATE = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2019-02-14","2019-02-15","2019-02-16","2019-02-17","2019-02-18","2019-02-19","2019-02-20","2019-02-21", 
"2019-04-03","2019-04-04","2019-04-05"), class = "factor"), NONCOVEREDCHARGES = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), COVEREDCHARGES = c(216, 
496.68, 150, 610, 6259.73, 1020.97), HCE_TARGET_AMT = c(216,496.68, 150, 610, 6259.73, 1020.97)),.Names = c("TOTALCHARGES", 
"PARENTCLIENTCODE", "RECEIVEDDATE", "NONCOVEREDCHARGES", "COVEREDCHARGES", 
"HCE_TARGET_AMT"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: hi, i cannot reproduce your error. I suspect there's something weird with your data frame. can you do dput(head(data)), and paste output as part of your question?

Comment: dput(head(data))
structure(list(TOTALCHARGES = c(216, 496.68, 150, 610, 6259.73, 1020.97), PARENTCLIENTCODE = structure(c(468L, 253L, 456L, 456L, 43L, 167L), .Label = c("5STAR-P", "AAE-P", "AALT-P", "ABA-P", 
"ABN-P", "ACN-P","XIND-P","XKAI-P","XOXF-P","XPACI-P","XPIC-P","XRX-P","XSFH-P","XSISTERP"), class = "factor"), RECEIVEDDATE = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2019-02-14","2019-02-15","2019-02-16","2019-02-17","2019-02-18","2019-02-19","2019-02-20","2019-02-21", 
"2019-04-03","2019-04-04","2019-04-05"), class = "factor"),

Comment: NONCOVEREDCHARGES = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), COVEREDCHARGES = c(216, 
496.68, 150, 610, 6259.73, 1020.97), HCE_TARGET_AMT = c(216,496.68, 150, 610, 6259.73, 1020.97)),.Names = c("TOTALCHARGES", 
"PARENTCLIENTCODE", "RECEIVEDDATE", "NONCOVEREDCHARGES", "COVEREDCHARGES", 
"HCE_TARGET_AMT"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: hello, i have added dput(head(data)) as requested. please look into. thank you

Comment: You are grouping by two variables. Is it possible that some combinations have no rows? Try `xtabs(~PARENTCLIENTCODE+RECEIVEDDATE, data)`. If some cells are zero, that could be the problem. Splitting the data into groups and deleting the empty groups could resolve the problem.